# jQuery - get width of all li within a ul

Tags: jquery, dynamic, width

I have a ul. Within the ul there are x number of li. Within the li there is a single image.

That is:

```
<ul>
    <li>image</li>
    <li>image</li>
    <li>image</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to be able to get the total width of the ul. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you meant by total width? Do you need number of `li` or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

```
var internaWidth = $("ul").width();
// or
var widthIncludingPadding = $("ul").outerWidth();
// or
var widthIncludingMargin = $("ul").outerWidth(true);
```

Depending on what you need

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should give an id to ul then this code may solve the problem:

```
<ul id="myul">
  <li>image</li>
  <li>image</li>
  <li>image</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var totalWidth = $("#myul").width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul").width()
```

Will get you the width of the ul element.